# How to search a 1 x 9 x N dimension np.array for a 1 x 9 dimension np.array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I am solving the 8 Puzzle Problem. After creating the possible move states and selecting the best one, I am appending the array for the current best move, to an array called used set.

```
bestMove = 
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

usedSet =
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Without any knowledge of what its previous moves are, the program gets stuck going left and right. I would like the program to see that it has made that move before and not accept it as the best move.

I am not sure how I can compare my current best move to the arrays in the used set. I thought i could use the any or all command but hit a dead end with that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason to use numpy arrays this seems like a better fit for the Python built-in types:

You can encode your moves as `tuple`s and store them in a `set`:

```
>>> usedset = set()
>>> bestmove = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
>>> usedset.add(bestmove)
>>> bestmove in usedset

True
```

Note you need to use a tuple rather than a numpy array (or a list) because tuples are hashable, which is a requirement for them to be stored in a `set`. Membership checks are O(1) in sets, so this is actually pretty fast.

In order to implement this in your code, you will use that `in` statement with an if, something like this:

```
bestmove = get_best_move()
if bestmove not in usedset:
    usedset.add(bestmove)
    evaluate_move(bestmove)
```

If you absolutely have to use numpy arrays, you can convert them going in:

```
usedset.add(tuple(bestmove))
```

will work if `bestmove` is a numpy array.

Comment: I tried to implement the set with my code. I got the numpy arrays to convert and reshape to the 1 x 9 format. It will add to the set. But how can i stop the if statement if the tuple is already in the set?

    `code` if tuple(map(tuple, np.reshape(a, (1, 9)))) in usedSet`code`

Comment: I've extended the answer with an example of checking if the move is in usedset. Basically you use the `in` operator.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I got the program running and able to solve a puzzle that took over 60 steps! Now its time to make the output a little bit prettier, instead of this debug nest of a first true program that I have made.